# Case when statement not working as an aggregate expression

Tags: sql, presto

I'm getting an error in my code saying that my case when part of the query has to be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause

the code that I currently have is:

```
case
when advertiser_currency
like 'GBP' then sum(try_Cast(revenue_adv_currency AS DOUBLE)*1.15)
else sum(TRY_CAST(revenue_adv_currency AS DOUBLE)*1)
end AS amount_spent_EUR
```

How can I make this into an aggregate function?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the case inside the aggregation

```
 SUM ( case when advertiser_currency like 'GBP' 
            then try_Cast(revenue_adv_currency AS DOUBLE) * 1.15
            else try_Cast(revenue_adv_currency AS DOUBLE) * 1.0
       end 
     ) AS amount_spent_EUR
```

Comment: @Aki, I'm glad you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left (which will then turn green as Juan pointed out). It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too

Comment: @EricBrandt Also show the question as solve on the list so other dont waste time checking the question .